# Can't change background color of loop generated div

Tags: javascript, loops

I generated some divs with a loop and I can't change their color (or any of their properties) via aJavaScript event listener (The console log works, so the event listener is working).

```
const main = document.getElementById('divmain');
let parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('div');
  p.classList.add("pixel");
  parent.appendChild(p);
  p.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  p.style.color = 'blue';
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.pixel')) return;
  console.log("Hello World");
  p.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}, false);
```

The background should change to yellow but not

Answer (score 0):

Keep your dev tools open so you can see when errors are thrown - it says that `p` is not defined. You defined `p` in your for loop, but you are referencing it in your listener func, which does not have `p` in scope. You would be better off doing something like this:

```js
const main = document.getElementById('divmain');
let parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  let p = document.createElement('div');
  p.classList.add("pixel");
  parent.appendChild(p);
  p.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  p.style.color = 'blue'

  // add an event listener for each p
  p.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log("Hello World");
    p.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="divmain">
  <div id="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p` variable is not defined. Either you need to set a listener in the loop as @twharmon suggested or use `event.target` instead of `p`:

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```